# Почему не хватает опер. памяти для ffmpeg?

Tags: bash, cmd, bat, видео, ffmpeg

Батником запускаю ffmpeg который накладывает HUD-видео поверх другого (overlay). Подсмотрел этот метод тут: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269387/ffmpeg-overlay-one-video-onto-another-video)

При запуске батника, ffmpeg начинает "рендерить это" и через 1-2минуты начинаются на компе жуткие тормоза, в диспетчере задач вижу сожрало 12 Гб RAM из 16 доступных. потом даже курсор еле-еле двигается.

Спустя минуты 2 вылетает ошибка что памяти не хватает:
[image: error]

Вот характеристики ноута:
[image: komp]

Как решить проблему с зависанием и вылетом на ошибку?

**Код батника:**

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for %%i in (*.mov *.mp4 *.mts) do (
  md "result_%%~ni"
ffmpeg -i "%%i" -i "res/intro 2018.mp4" -filter_complex "[1:v]setpts=PTS-10/TB[a]; [0:v][a]overlay=enable=gte(t\,5):shortest=1[out]" -map [out] -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy -y result_%%~ni\%%~ni%%03d.mp4

) 
pause
```

увеличил файл подкачки и рендер не завис, но вот какой файл получился https://disk.yandex.ru/d/rlFPV9d33R0byg он почему-то без видео.
Файл подкачки:
[image: swapp]